# Does shock web damage stack?

Tags: diablo-ii

The assasin in Diablo II has the shock web ability. You can throw it down and the lighting lasts for a while. So it is possible to throw multiple shockwebs on a single spot. Visually it kinda looks like it should do more damage, but is that true? Does the shockweb lighting damage stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. Shock Web has a frame limit (24) on the number of times an enemy can be hit with attacks in a certain period of time. You won't hit more often, the damage doesn't stack, but you won't have to wait for Shock Web to be cast when the previous one runs out.

When an enemy is hit with Shock Web, they become essentially immune to damage for 24 frames. After that frame limit is over, they can be hit again by something else.

If you throw 50 Shock Webs on top of an enemy at the same time, only 1 Shock Web will hit every 24 frames.

The only benefit you get from overlapping Shock Web is to guarantee that there will always be a Shock Web available to hit an enemy in case the previous one expires.

Comment: Do you mean that shockweb A is able to hit while shockweb B is in "framelimit mode"?

Comment: No, the enemies are in "framelimit mode", shockweb applies the "framelimit mode" - I'll try to go into more detail with examples in my answer

Comment: Hmm, interesting. You said immune to damage for 24 frames. Does that mean that if you have a really low leveled shock web, that  does less damage than your other traps, can even be harmful for your dps?

Comment: 1000000% yes. This is also true for any other attack in the game that applies this frame rule.